# When is $f(y)$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

Find all prime numbers that can be expressed as :
 $f(y)=y^{2015}+y+1$, where $y$ is a natural number. $y=1$ gives us 3, but how do we find others or prove that there can be no other??

Comment: shouldn't it be $y^{2015}$? You forgot you curly brackets.

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the fact that 
$$x^{2015}+x+1 = x^{2015}-x^2+(x^2+x+1)=x^2(x^{3\times 671}-1)+(x^2+x+1) = x^2(x^{3}-1)(x^{3\times 670}+x^{3\times 669}+\dots+x^3+1)+(x^2+x+1) = (x^2+x+1)(x^2(x-1)A+1)$$
where $A = x^{3\times 670}+x^{3\times 669}+\dots+x^3+1$

Comment: You should check the exponents again.

Comment: Still not clear: $x^{2015}-x^2=x^2(x^{2013}-1)$. Where does the $3671$ come from?

Comment: @gammatester Sorry for the confusion. With $.$ I mean product.

Comment: I wish you had told me "try to factorise it" as a hint. HAHA